# Disk cleanup using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script for cleaning disks. All works except running `cleanmgr`. Can someone advise?

```
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace(0xA)
$computername = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter machine name'

foreach ($hosts in $computername) {
  #$temp = get-ChildItem "env:\TEMP"
  #$temp2 = $emp.Value
  #$swtools = "c:\SWTOOLS\*"
  $ccmcache = "\\$hosts\c$\Windows\ccmcache\*"
  $temp = "\\$hosts\C$\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\*"
  #$WinTemp = "c:\Windows\Temp\*"

  $FreespaceBefore = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $hosts -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | select Freespace).FreeSpace/1GB

  #Write-Output "Disk Space Before"
  Write-Output "$FreespaceBefore"

  Write-Host "Removing Junk files in $ccmcache on $hosts." -ForegroundColor Green
  Remove-Item -Recurse $ccmcache -Force -Verbose

  Write-Host "Removing Junk files in $temp on $hosts." -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
  Remove-Item -Recurse $temp -Force -Verbose

  Write-Host "Finally now , Running Windows disk Clean up Tool" -ForegroundColor Cyan

  Invoke-Command -ComputerName pc -ScriptBlock {Start-Process cleanmgr.exe}

  #Write-Output "Disk Space after"
  #Write-Output "$diskspaceafter"

  $([char]7)
  Sleep 1
  $([char]7)
  Sleep 1

  Write-Host "I finished the cleanup task,Succefully " -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
```

Comment: `cleanmgr.exe` normally starts an interactive GUI. That doesn't work when running the program on a remote host via `Invoke-Command`. You need to add the [appropriate parameter(s)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315246) to make it run without user interaction. Also, the program runs asynchronously, i.e. the call returns immediately without waiting for the program to terminate, so you may want to use `Start-Process -Wait`.

Answer (score 0):

## 2# Running Disk Clean up Tool

```
write-Host "Finally now , Running Windows disk Clean up Tool" -ForegroundColor Cyan
cleanmgr /sagerun:1 /VERYLOWDISK | out-Null 

$([char]7)
Sleep 1 
$([char]7)
Sleep 1
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for a remote computer. Works well locally

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but for anyone still looking...

This link could provide a couple [options](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2011709-disk-cleanup-across-domain-computers), like the one below

```
foreach ($computer in $computers){
if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
{write-host "cannot reach $computer" -f red}

else {& \\$computer\C$\Windows\System32\cleanmgr.exe /sagerun:1}}
```